# Asp.net identity. Remember me, don't work

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I create a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project. Authentication change: store user accounts in-app.

Adding new scaffolded item -> Identity -> Choose Account\login and Register

Setting:

```
ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
 
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

Next I ran `Update-database`:

> User registration is successful.

But if I log in with the "Remember me" flag. Then the next time I go to the logging page. Fields name and password is empty. How to implement auto-filling of these fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "remember me" option determines whether the authentication cookie persists beyond the current browser session. It doesn't - and shouldn't - attempt to persist your credentials anywhere.

All modern browsers have built-in password managers, and there are plenty of extensions available for third-party password managers. Let the browser take care of remembering the login details. Anything else will inevitably be horrendously insecure.

[Troy Hunt: How to build (and how not to build) a secure “remember me” feature](https://www.troyhunt.com/how-to-build-and-how-not-to-build/)

Comment: And if the "Remember me" checkbox is selected, how I can open in chrome, show the window password saving ?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the "remember me" checkbox. Chrome, or any other modern browser, will offer to save the credentials when the user logs in, and offer to use the saved credentials when the user goes back to the login page. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: The problem is that in the browser, a window "remember password" open one time (if you choose to remember or not). Is it possible to call this window if necessary?

Comment: @Denis **The user** can chose how to manage their own passwords. Your code cannot.